# OR condition failling while getting file extension of uploaded file.

Tags: php

Below is the code and i am not sure what am i doing wrong here. Because it seems like OR conditions are not executing properly.

```
$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
     $folder="uploads/";


$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($ext != 'doc' or $ext != 'docx' or $ext != 'pdf'){
        $errmsg_arr1[] = 'Your file must be word or pdf document.';
        $errmsg_arr1[] = $ext;
        $errflag = true;
    }
```

When i upload file (doc, docx or pdf) it is still showing me message "Your file must be word or pdf document."

I checked the value in ext and it is showing me docx.

Can anyone advise me what am i doing wrong? There might be silly mistake which i am not able to find right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is invalid:

`docx` is not `doc` so your first condition `$ext != 'doc'` is **true**.

It must be:

```
if($ext != 'doc' && $ext != 'docx' && $ext != 'pdf'){
    // warn user
```

Comment: How stupid i am. Thanks Mate.